# What does it mean to have a 'slash chord' with more than one note after the slash?

Tags: chords, notation

I'm used to slash chords like D/F# or Am/G where the second part after the slash informs you of the bass note.

I just saw a video with someone talking about chords like C+/Db+. I didn't even know slash chords could be used like this, what does this more complex notation actually *mean*?

Also, is there a more proper name for these chords than 'slash'?

Comment: Yes, you can technically have more superimposed chords, but it's a bit strange to have two chords that are only a semitone apart. What video is it?

Comment: @musicamante a bit off-topic but it was an ear-training demo by Rick Beato. I guess it was chosen to be deliberately very difficult

Comment: Can you give us a link so that we could better understand what it's about?

Comment: I remember seeing a question bringing up at least somewhat related notation with a _ with one chord on top and another below, with the example taken from *The Phantom of the Opera*.

Comment: It looks like a polychord notation, but that would be odd unless it's a very advanced ear-training video. A screenshot from the video, plus a link to the video, would be helpful.

Comment: Lawrence’s answer is on the money but I just want to point out the distinction between the two is poly chords should use a horizontal line (see his second chord) but chords with bass notes other than the root should use a slash (his third chord).

Comment: The question about the Kurt Rosenwinkel piece is mainly about his failure to properly differentiate between slash bass and polychord notation. Not really a duplicate of this one.  Where do we vote to reinstate it?

Comment: @LaurencePayne In the line just above the comments (where you should see an option for "Share," "Edit," "Flag," etc.) there should be a "Reopen" option.

Comment: @Richard  Thanks.  Or perhaps you take the point and could just reverse your decision?

Comment: @LaurencePayne I'm happy to be overruled here, but I still think the linked duplicate answers this question. In fact, I think those answers (your own included) answer this question even *better* than your answer here.

Comment: I think the other question _answers_ my question, but I would never have found it with such a specific title!

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking at a Polychord.  One chord on top of another.  Often both triads, but the system allows more complex chords.

Sometimes a harmonic device all its own, sometimes a method of simplifying the notation of an extended chord.

Stravinsky used them (though he was unlikely to have labelled them with chord symbols!)  As did ALW in 'Phantom' (where he did. Show-off!)

Chord symbols live on the border between harmonic analysis and practical reading aid.  When you end a jazz-styled piece with a nice 'dirty' Cmaj13(♯11) you might well think of it, for practical playing purposes, as a D over Cmaj7 polychord.  Purely as an aid to where your fingers go, no deep harmonic meaning.

[image]

Comment: So we think it might be slightly lazy/loose notation in the video I saw, because a slash chord _does_ only allow a single note to be specified?